# Python // Remove String // Array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an array including u-strings like this (the array can be larger or shorter; also the elements occurrence can be different)

```
[u'Alpha Beta Gamma', u'Delta-Espilon Phi', u'Alpha&Omega Theta', u'Delta&Epsilon Ny', u'Delta Gamma Xeta Theta 53422']
```

I would like to remove all elements from the array that do not include delta? If the delta is included the whole element should stay. The array should shrink to the size of elements that include delta.

Has anybody a way how to?

Comment: There are many ways of doing that. What is yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to perform this filtering

```
>>> [i for i in l if 'Delta' in i]
['Delta-Espilon Phi', 'Delta&Epsilon Ny', 'Delta Gamma Xeta Theta 53422']
```

Comment: indubitably. questions should be discouraged on question sites!

Comment: Good questions should be encouraged. Good questions contain MCVE's and aren't just a requirement dump and "can haz code plz?"